# Changing the properties of an object from another object in JAVA

Tags: java, object, properties

Do i have to create an instance of an object to be able to modify it's properties?

I have a window that have option on the color and speed of a ball. In the other window I have an animation of a bal going up and down. I want the window with the option to control properties such as color and speed of the ball. Can i do that without creating an instance of the ball object? I've created some setter in my ball class.

Comment: Show us your code instead of describing it.

Comment: Make use of static keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is an object-oriented language. If you want to modify the properties of an object, then it must exist, as you cannot modify something which does not even exist.

However, you can define class-level properties using the `static` keyword. `static` properties are `class`-level, therefore you do not need to instantiate an object of the given `class` to modify a `static` member.

For instance, if you have a `class` called `Bird`, then a `Bird` can have instance-level properties, such as `color`. You can only modify the `color` of a `Bird` if it exists and through that `Bird`. You can also have a `static` property, like `numberOfBirds`, which defines a property of the `Bird` `class`, not `Bird` objects. You modify it through your `class`:

```
public class Bird{

    public String color = null;
    public static int numberOfBirds = 0;
    //...
}
```

Modifying the properties:

```
//...
Bird myBird = new Bird(); //instantiating a bird
myBird.color = "black"; //modifying the color of a given bird
Bird.numberOfBirds++;
//...
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you got some concepts mixed up a little bit.

In Java, objects are instances of classes. A class is the blueprint, the plan, the design, the model of something, an object is the actual thing.

As a class is an abstract concept, you cannot modify its properties at runtime.
It's the objects whose properties you can modify.
Here's an example:

```
Ball ball = new Ball();
```

`Ball` is a class, `ball` is an object. This object is an instance of the `Ball` class.

If the `Ball` class defines some setters, like `setColor`, `setSpeed`, you can use those to modify properties of this `ball` object.

Comment: Koszi, a tied meg jobb, +1 ;-)